# MYSQL Col1 Sum Based on COL2 Grouping

Tags: mysql

I am querying a Wordpress postmeta table to try and pull some sales information by customer. How can I get the customers to be grouped together. The challenge here is that all the data is in the postmeta table.

Heres my unsuccessful attempt so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", metaA.meta_value, metaB.meta_value) AS customer_name, metaC.meta_value AS 'Total'
FROM wp_postmeta AS metaA
JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaB USING (post_id)
JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaC USING (post_id)
WHERE (metaA.meta_key = '_billing_first_name')
AND (metaB.meta_key = '_billing_last_name')
AND (metaC.meta_key = '_order_total')
GROUP BY metaA.meta_value, metaB.meta_value, metaC.meta_value
```

Results:

```
+---------------+---------+
| customer_name |  Total  |
+---------------+---------+
|     customer1 |      10 |
|     customer1 |      50 |
|     customer1 |      90 |
|     customer2 |      40 |
|     customer3 |      10 |
|     customer3 |      10 |
|     customer4 |      20 |
+---------------+---------+
```

I am trying to get:

```
+---------------+---------+
| customer_name |  Total  |
+---------------+---------+
|     customer1 |     150 |
|     customer2 |      40 |
|     customer3 |      20 |
|     customer4 |      20 |
+---------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by the concatenated customer name and sum the metaC.meta_value:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", metaA.meta_value, metaB.meta_value) AS customer_name, sum(metaC.meta_value) AS 'Total'
FROM wp_postmeta AS metaA
JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaB USING (post_id)
JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaC USING (post_id)
WHERE (metaA.meta_key = '_billing_first_name')
    AND (metaB.meta_key = '_billing_last_name')
    AND (metaC.meta_key = '_order_total')
GROUP BY CONCAT_WS(" ", metaA.meta_value, metaB.meta_value)
```

Comment: Better than using subquery. +1

Comment: I gave this one a shot too, but it too gives some strange sums.

Comment: @DarkSpartan47 you need to describe exactly the unexpected behaviour because I do not see your data and your feedback does not contain any points I could use to modify the solution.

Comment: @Shadow you are correct, the math is still not correct with the selected answer. I will update with my results.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the confusion was my fault. The math is correct, the issue I ran into was the _order_total included values from orders that where perhaps deleted or draft. I switched it to use 'Net Revenue From Stripe' and it resulted in the number I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", metaA.meta_value, metaB.meta_value) AS customer_name, SUM(metaC.meta_value) AS 'Total'
FROM wp_postmeta AS metaA
    JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaB USING (post_id)
    JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaC USING (post_id)
WHERE (metaA.meta_key = '_billing_first_name')
    AND (metaB.meta_key = '_billing_last_name')
    AND (metaC.meta_key = '_order_total')
GROUP BY metaA.meta_value, metaB.meta_value
```

Comment: That groups the names but doesn't sum up the second columns values

Comment: hey, it sums up correctly, I checked it. Please, try again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT customer_name, sum(total) as total from
(SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", metaA.meta_value, metaB.meta_value) AS customer_name, metaC.meta_value AS 'Total'
FROM wp_postmeta AS metaA
JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaB USING (post_id)
JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaC USING (post_id)
WHERE (metaA.meta_key = '_billing_first_name')
AND (metaB.meta_key = '_billing_last_name')
AND (metaC.meta_key = '_order_total')
GROUP BY metaA.meta_value, metaB.meta_value, metaC.meta_value) t
Group by customer_name
```

Comment: Perfect, that fixed my broken sums too! Thank You.

Comment: what is the t for at the end of the first group by

Comment: If you `GROUP BY metaA.meta_value, metaB.meta_value, metaC.meta_value` it will hide _order_total which are the same.

Comment: DarkSpartan, if you don't add the `t` MySQL will throw the error "Every derived table must have its own alias". So, it's simply an alias to identify then subquery. BTW, I think Shadow's and myself answers are more efficient. What MySQL version are you using that those didn't work for you?

Comment: Your answer yields a different resultthan mine because if for the same customer you have the same C value, then your subquery keeps only one of them, while mine sums them up. If your query yields the correct result, then the OP messed up the question because this important information was left out.

Answer (score -1):

The script below should work for you:

```
SELECT customer_name, sum(total_order) from
(
  SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", metaA.meta_value, metaB.meta_value) AS customer_name, metaC.meta_value AS total_order
  FROM wp_postmeta AS metaA
  JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaB USING (post_id)
  JOIN wp_postmeta AS metaC USING (post_id)
  WHERE (metaA.meta_key = '_billing_first_name')
  AND (metaB.meta_key = '_billing_last_name')
  AND (metaC.meta_key = '_order_total')
)
group by customer_name
```